# How to search from a list of remote file

Tags: debian, remote, search

I've a file which contains a list of remote files:

```
/trunk/a.java
/trunk/b.java
/tags/v1/a.java
```

I need to search a string into these files' contains. But they're remote file so I need to prefix them with a `http://` part.

How can I do it ? I know `cat` and `grep` command but I don't know how to iterate over my file list, and concatains with a prefix...

Comment: By remote you say they are on a webserver only? Or do you also have `ssh` access? Is downloading them (e.g. via `wget`) an option?

Comment: @Fiximan Webserver, actually it's files managed by a svn server.

Comment: Do you just need to know which files have the string or anything more?

Comment: @Fiximan just to know which files contain my string, then I'll access them with a subversion tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `listoffiles` is the file with the list of names,
and they all start with / so you want to prefix with "http:/",
and use curl, say, to get the file, you can do something simple like:

```
while read file
do    if curl "http:/$file" | grep 'my pattern'
  then svn ..."$file"...
  fi
done <listoffiles
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the `curl` part. I would suggest `if [[ $(wget -O /dev/stdout "http..$file" | grep 'string') ]] ; then `

Comment: @Fiximan I used wget too